# Raphael is not defined

Tags: javascript, raphael

my html code look like this

```
<script src="js/raphael/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="js/raphael/g.raphael.js"></script>
<script src="js/raphael/g.bar.js"></script>
```

But my developer tool says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined g.raphael.js:7
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined g.bar.js:19

when i load the page and look at the developer console

I have offcourse downloaded all the files and placed them in the shown locations.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check your path again!

Comment: Make sure raphael is there!

Comment: As you can see on the error code the first raphael.js doesnt generate an error. So it is found and loaded succesfully. And since the 2 other errors are a js error from within the js files, they are found too.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `js/raphael/raphael.js` is not valid path.

Comment: its line 7 in g.raphael.js and line 19 in g.bar.js thats failing. How can they that if the files arent found?
If i change the path in src= i geet an GET error

Comment: g.raphael.js and g.bar.js are libraries from the same domain (raphaeljs.com) and I don't think what is the Dmitry Baranovskiy and his team error. Such errors are the results of 404 error for main file via (js/raphael/raphael.js). So check your path or load again raphael from [official site](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: I am sure there is no error in the js files. I was just wondering if i did something wrong so they caused an error.
I have tried downloading them again, the -min files this time but i get the same error.
I have more than 10 other js files included and none of them fail, and they are all located in the same folder and all paths are identical.
As far as i can see the first raphael.js should initialize the var raphael so the other files can use it. But that doesnt happen

Comment: Change first raphael script src attribute to github row path  - https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/master/raphael-min.js and post here are error still write?

Comment: it got an execute error so i changed it to rawgithub.com/etc and got the same error as the i described in the question. so no change

Comment: I create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKGkD/) and set raphael and all dependencies from github. All works. Can you create your fiddle or any example to show errors?

Comment: not surprisingly it said
Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined 

And after all the other not defined errors.

It seems my index.html somehow cant initialize raphael.js. I just dont dont know why :(

Comment: haha i tried moving the src="raphael.js" up in front of all the other not raphael related links and all errors dissapeared:
Strange, but atleast i can try and use it now

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with an `XPages` approach under `Domino Server`.

Found out that `Dojo Toolkit` - which automatically gets added to every XPage - is not compatible with `Raphael`.

Removed `Dojo` from the page, used `jQuery` instead - everything fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Paste these files** `raphael.js`, `g.raphael.js`, `g.bar.js` **where your html/jsp files reside**.

You will get ride of `ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined` this problem.